# Shouldn't bool return type always return true or false?

Tags: c#, .net

This is a method which returns true or false based on list count.
I always thought a bool return type needs to return either `true` or `false`. I do not understand this.
If the question is too silly I apologize.

```
private static bool AdjustIndexForList<t>(IList<t> list, ref int index)
{
 if(index<0)
  index += list.count;
 else if (index >= list.count)
   index = list.count - 1;
//I do not understand this part. What is this returning?
return index >= 0;
}
```

Here is the call to method

```
if(!adjustIndexForList(list, ref minIndex)
return false;
```

Comment: If index is larger than 0 or equal it returns true. Other than that false.

Comment: You can always check by throwing something like `(4 >= 1).GetType()` in the interactive window (or a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7BpN5F)) and it'll give you `System.Boolean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>=` is called as **greater than equal to comparison operator** which checks left and right operand and returns `true` if left hand side count is greater than or equal to right hand side count otherwise `false`.

In your case,

> `return index >= 0;`  it will return `true` if index is greater than
>   equal to zero otherwise it returns `false`.

---

```
if(index >= 0)   //execute if block if index is greater than equal to zero
    return true;  // return true
```

one liner solution for above if condition is,

```
return index >= 0; //returns "true" if index is greater than equal to zero
```

Comment: I think we should break the sequence of the execution into 2 steps. First it compares index and 0, and give result as true/false. Then it "return" the result.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe, writing this code in two steps is depend on developer. I would have done it in single line, but for beginner or making your code more readable we can do it as you mentioned in your comment

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have been able to find it. I did not really think that it could be used outside if syntax.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar By doing it one line you mean using ternary operatioin? But even after that I cant see it in one line I am trying(not question your intelligence, I am just curious how would you do it).

Comment: Ok got it I thought the whole block of statement is what you were talking about. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an evaluation, and returns true or false:

```
return index >= 0;
```

It reads as:

```
return (index is greater than or equal to zero)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see there is a 'condensed' version of a typical `if-else` clause.

I'm sure you can easily understand the following code:

```
bool result = false;
if (index >= 0)
    result = true;
else
    result = false;
return result;
```

And your code does exactly the same thing.

To further explain, the condition check `index >= 0` evaluates into a `Boolean`. That means the result of that check is either `true` or `false`. So, means you can do this:

```
bool result = index >= 0;
return result;
```

But then, why stop there? We can get rid of the `result` variable as well since we only use it to return, so we simply do this:

```
return index >= 0;
```

Essentially, it's coding syntax C# gives us to write shorter/concise code.

Comment: Yup the first part of your code is what I was thinking about when I initially saw it.